# How to select records from a Postgres table using an ORDER BY statement on a jsonb column that points to another table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-order-by, jsonb

I have two tables, `characteristics` and `students`.

**characteristics**

```
 id      name          value
----    ------        -------
 1      country       england
 2      country       brazil
 3      games         football
 4      games         baseball
 5      country       india
 .        .             .
 .        .             .
```

**students**

```
 first_name      age       character_values
------------    -----     ------------------
  Jason          12         [1,4]
  Mark           14         [1,3] 
  Kunal          10         [5,3] 
   .              .           .
   .              .           .
   .              .           .
```

The `characteristics` table has three columns where the `id` column is an auto-increment field. The `name` denotes the name of a specific characteristic and the `value` indicates the respective information about the characteristic.

The `students` table contains detail about each student. The `character_value` field in the `students` table is a `jsonb` field. Each element in the jsonb array is an ID that points to the appropriate characteristic ID in the `characteristics` table.

(for example, if a student is from the country of india then the ID 5 is appended to `character_values` jsonb array against the respective student's name)

Assuming that each student can only belong to one country, how do I select a list of students while ordering the result by the name of the country they belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables with `jsonb_array_elements`:

```
select c.*, s.first_name from characteristics c join students s on exists 
  (select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(s.character_values) v where v.value::int = c.id)
```

Output:

| id | name | value | first_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | country | england | Jason |
| 1 | country | england | Mark |
| 3 | games | football | Mark |
| 3 | games | football | Kunal |
| 4 | games | baseball | Jason |
| 5 | country | india | Kunal |

Comment: Why did you use a SELECT 1 instead of SELECT *? Any specific reason?

Comment: @Vinay `select 1` is convention for `exists` subqueries.